# Embedding a select within a trigger

Tags: plsql, triggers

I have about 20 read-only schemas that need access to the production database. I do not want to create synonyms over DBLink so I found a solution online to create a trigger to assist me. All my read-only users have a similar profile attached to them: "profile1".

Below is the example of the trigger that works:

```
create or replace Trigger logon_trig
After Logon on Database
Begin
  IF USER in ('USER1','USER2') THEN
       execute immediate 'ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=PRODDB';
  END IF;
Exception
  When others then
    Null;
End;
```

Question:

I would like the trigger to select all the users with the profile "profile1" instead of me hard-coding all usernames in the trigger syntax.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could count the number of matching rows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER logon_trig
AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
DECLARE
    v_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT USERNAME, PROFILE, ACCOUNT_STATUS FROM DBA_USERS; 

    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO   v_count
    FROM   dba_users
    WHERE  username = USER AND profile = 'profile1';

    IF v_count = 0 THEN
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=PRODDB';
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHER THEN
        NULL;
END;
```